# is there a pre-build solution for generating a package.xml from a git repo

Tags: deployment, package.xml

i have the metadata's pushed into a git repo, after making changes and tested in my individual sandbox. While trying to deploy to the higher env, i am trying to get a package.xml generated by itself, based on the files that have changed.

Have anyone done this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is this awesome tool on github https://github.com/amtrack/force-dev-tool

You can use following command to create a changeset:

```
$ git diff master feature/vat | force-dev-tool changeset create vat
```

Comment: i seriously think this is what i am looking for. Espicially the cool feature of generating the `package.xml` via the `git diff`. I will test it out further and will let you know.

Comment: As `force-dev-tool` is deprecated now in favor of Salesforce DX, does anybody know how to generate package XML from `git diff` using sfdx? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

As `force-dev-tool` is deprecated, here is a solution [(by the author of the tool - Matthias Rolke)](https://twitter.com/lukaszwebmaster/status/1242790310603821056) using Salesforce DX:

```
deployDir="$(mktemp -d)"
git diff --name-only --pretty="" develop feature/myfeature | paste -d, -s - | xargs -0 sfdx force:source:convert -d "${deployDir}" -p
```

(Please note that it doesn't handle destructive changes).

Comment: Any advice for if you receive the error `xargs: argument line too long`?

Answer (score 1):

There are (paid) tools that can do this, such as [GearSet](https://gearset.com/) (standard disclaimer: I am not affiliated with or endorse this product), which you can find both on the AppExchange and using Google searches. You can also build a [Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_apps.htm&type=0), include it as part of your source control, and use that package to deploy projects. You could also automatically generate a package.xml file using force:manifest:create from Salesforce DX. You'll want to look at the documentation for more details. Generally speaking, it's still acceptable to deploy *all* components, however, as it generally just takes longer to deploy in the worse case scenario.

Comment: Apart from the gain in deployment time, are there any down-side in deploying only changed files/components? i can think of a dev missing out something in the package.xml , that have been changed. In case, we are going to construct/merge the package.xml 's

Comment: @OK999 Using an unmanaged package builds the package.xml for you when you retrieve it. It also validates that no components are missing. That said, it does generate a full deployment. A diff deployment is definitely faster. You may even want to combine the two to make sure you don't miss anything.